# Google sign-in through virtual cloud server

Tags: google-chrome, virtual-machine

This is a basic question.. I'm not developing an app or anything...

Just want to sign in to google via browser on a cloud-based virtual desktop (Ubuntu), but the sign-in page says my browser is not secure.

From what I've researched it seems google does not allow sign-in from an "embedded" browser.

Is there any easy way around this? Or maybe even a difficult way... ?